# What is the role of Grief according to Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, vedas

What is the role of [Grief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grief) acc. to scriptures? How is it categorised and on what basis?

- Do the Vedas mention any definitive relationship between the processing of grief and its consequent culminating in wisdom? If so, what do they have to say?
- On a related note, which vedic deities are associated with Grieving/Grief?

Comment: What an off-beat Q. 1. Conventional wisdom talks about smasaana vairaagyam (while ack'ing that it is transient. I can tell you the story of Vasishtha's grief that culminated into gnyana 2. Alakshmi or JyeshTha devi is associated with everything inauspicious including zOka. Don't know if she is a vedic deity although zrI sUktam which is a vedic hymn mentions alakshmi.

Comment: I would be interested in the story, can you point me to it? @moonstar2001

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan [What is the story of Alakshmi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7038/3500)

Comment: Grief can be due to the passing of a loved one and can make us realise the ephemeral nature of embodied existence, in that sense it has the power to give wisdom. So in this sense it is not exactly inauspicious i feel. @moonstar2001

Comment: @TheDestroyer Again, i'm not sure Grief specifically is always something that is inauspicious. And so, i'm doubtful about specific connection to Alakshmi

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Yes. grief may not  correlate  to Alakshmi. We also say one will get grief due to lack of fortune (Sri-Lakshmi).

Comment: Grief that is not overcome is inauspicious.Grief when dhairya lakshmi is absent is inauspicious.  Also the smasaana vairagyam is usually transient as I mentioned.