# What are the dwelling places of Sri Lakshmi Devi?

Tags: belief, lakshmi

We know that there are some liked and disliked places by [Alakshmi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7038/5212), who is elder sister of Goddess Lakshmi who was born out of churning of ocean. She was granted some places to dwell by the gods. These places are still believed to be favorite and unfavorite places of her by people.  Similarly, are the dwelling places of Goddess Lakshmi Devi stated any where in texts? I have heard that she likes places which are clean and tidy, also some objects like Gold etc., as favorite.

In simple words, what are favorite and unfavorite places of Goddess Lakshmi Devi?

Comment: Look no further than Srinivaasa!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where does goddess Laskshmi dwell?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-6-min-cost-path/) :P

Comment: @Rohit. That solved my "problem" :P

Answer (score 7):

Some places where Lakshmi Devi does not like to reside/dwell are given in the following passage:

> **Laksmî does not reside in that house where conch shells are not blown,
>   where there are no Tulasî trees, where there is no worship of S’iva
>   and S’ivâ, where the Brâhmanas are not fed. O Brâhman! O Devas! Where
>   I and My Bhaktas are blamed, Mahâ Laksmî becomes greatly displeased.
>   She instantly goes away out of that house**. Laksmî does not stay even
>   for a moment in that house where the stupid person, without any
>   devotion for me, takes his food on the Harivâsara Ekâdas’î day (the
>   eleventh day of the moon’s wane or increase) or on My anniversary
>   birthday. If anybody sells My name or his own daughter, where the
>   guests are not served, Laksmî quits that house instantly and goes
>   away.....
>   If the son of an unchaste woman be a Brâhmana, he and the husband of
>   an unchaste woman are great sinners. If anybody goes to such a
>   person’s house or eats the food of a S’ûdra during a Srâddha ceremony,
>   Laksmî becomes very angry and vacates that house. Being a Brâhmin, if
>   one burns a S’ûdra’s corpse, one becomes very wretched and the vilest
>   of the Brâhmins. Laksmî never stays for a moment more in that house.
>   Being a Brâhmin, if he be a S’ûdra’s cook and drives oxen, Laksmî
>   fears to drink water there and quits his house. Being a Brâhmin, if
>   his heart be unholy, if he be cruel, envies others and blames persons,
>   if he officiates as a priest for the S’ûdra, Laksmî Devî never stays
>   in his house. The World-Mother never stays even for a moment in his
>   house who eats at the house of one who marries an unmarried girl
>   twelve years old in whom menstruation has commenced. He who cuts grass
>   by his nails, or writes on the ground with his nails, or from whose
>   house a Brâhmana guest goes back disappointed, Laksmî never stays in
>   his house. If any Brâhmana eats food at the early sunrise, sleeps
>   during the day or engages in a sexual intercourse during the day,
>   Laksmî never stays in his house....

And, obviously the opposite of these places will be her favorite.

> 48-59. **Laksmî always remains there with the greatest gladness where
>   conch-shells are blown, where there are conchsells, the S’âlagrâma
>   stone, the Tulasî leaves and the service and meditation of Laksmî are
>   daily done. Where the phallic emblem of S’iva is worshipped, and His
>   glories sung, where S’rî Durgâ is worshipped and Her glories are sung,
>   Laksmî, the Dweller in the Lotus, remains there.** Where the Brâhmanas
>   are honoured and they are gladly feasted, where all the Devas are
>   worshiped; the chaste Laksmî, the Lotus-faced, remains there

These words are those of Lord Vishnu. And the source is [**Devi Bhagavata Purana Book 9; Chapter 41.**](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam53.htm)

Answer (score 4):

In [Mahabharata, Santi Parva, SECTION CCXXVIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b055.htm), Devi Lakshmi herself has told her favorite and unfavorite places. It is a dialog between Devi Lakshmi and Lord Indra.

> "Sree said, 'In the three worlds full of the seeds of auspiciousness, all creatures, mobile and immobile, strive with their whole hearts to win an association with me. I am that Padma, that Sree decked with lotuses, who sprang from the lotus that blooms at the touch of the rays of Surya, for the prosperity of all creatures. I am called Lakshmi, Bhuti, and Sree, O slayer of Vala! I am Faith, I am Intelligence, I am Affluence, I am Victory, and I am Immutability. I am Patience, I am Success, I am Prosperity. I am Swaha, I am Swadha, I am Reverence, I am Fate, and I am Memory. **I dwell at the van and on the standards of victorious and virtuous sovereigns, as also in their homes and cities and dominions. I always reside, O slayer of Vala, with those foremost of men, viz., heroes panting after victory and unretreating from battle. I also reside for ever with persons that are firmly attached to virtue, that are endued with great intelligence, that are devoted to Brahma, that are truthful in speech, that are possessed of humility, and that are liberal. Formerly, I dwelt with the Asuras in consequence of my disposition of being bound by truth and merit Seeing, however, that the Asuras have assumed adverse natures, I have left then and wish to reside in thee.**'

I only quoted some points because this whole chapter is dedicated to Devi Lakshmi favorite and unfavorite things and places.